# Bootstrap tooltip bug when hovering child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, bootstrap-5

I have a bunch of elements builded in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.hasTooltip',
    trigger: "hover"
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Tooltip text" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <i class="fas fa-user m-0"></i>                                
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Other tooltip text" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span>Any child element</span>                                
</button>
```

So when I hover a tootlip target it shows the tooltip nicely. The problem is when I hover any child element of that tooltip element.

The element suddenly dissapears or is being repositioned at the top left corner of the view, breaking the entire behaviour of this Bootstrap component. No matters if it is an icon or a simply span node.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: do you have to use beta version of bootstrap 5. Why dont you prefer stable version like 4.1?

Comment: Certainly, this issue doesn't appears in earlier versions of Bootstrap, like 4.6. But i'm developing in a workflow where i'll need to stay updated.

I could change the bootstrap version, but I've done all migration process already. It would be a huge headache to undo all the changes I've done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `bootstrap bundle CDN` with `alpha3` and replace `JS` code as per `Bootstrap 5` `Tooltip` code.

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Tooltip text" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <i class="fas fa-user m-0"></i>                                
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Other tooltip text" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span>Any child element</span>                                
</button>
```

Comment: Ok I tried it and it works. But still dont think is the best option because I don't want to let my code outdated of the latest release. So I posted this in the official Github issues pannel and someone replied me to put the `pointer-events: none !important;` ccs rule. Which is a workaround until the next release. If no one suggest other approach, I'll mark this as a solution.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that this is the issue in the bootstrap 5 beta version. But I have also used the bootstrap 5 bundle but it's an alpha version, not beta1. Check the bundle CDN url.